# ST_Distance beetwen multiple points

Tags: sql, postgresql, geolocation, geometry, postgis

I have two tables, `public.street_lights` and `public.roads`.

There's a column `wkb_geometry` (type `geometry`) in both.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    ST_Distance(ST_Transform((SELECT wkb_geometry 
                              FROM public.street_lights 
                              WHERE ogc_fid = 1), 2855),
    ST_Transform((SELECT wkb_geometry 
                  FROM public.roads 
                  WHERE ogc_fid = 1), 2855))
```

Returns distance between road (id = 1) and light (id = 1).

My question is: how I can modify my query to check distance between light (id = 1) and every road?

Second question: how I should modify query to add new column to `public.street_lights` where will be `road_id` with distance is minimum. In other words: I need to find for every light - `road_id` from `roads` where distance is minimum.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need is to get rid of the subqueries and simply place the tables in the `WHERE` clause. If I understood you correctly, you wanted to get a single value with the closest road to a given light, so all you need compute the distance to all possible roads, `ORDER BY` the result and get the first value, e.g:

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE public.street_lights (ogc_fid INT, wkb_geometry GEOMETRY);
CREATE TABLE public.roads (ogc_fid INT, wkb_geometry GEOMETRY);

INSERT INTO street_lights VALUES (1,'SRID=4326;POINT(1 2)');
INSERT INTO roads VALUES (1,'SRID=4326;POINT(1 2.50)'),
                         (2,'SRID=4326;POINT(1 2.42)');
```

Query

```
SELECT roa.ogc_fid, ST_Distance(ST_Transform(lig.wkb_geometry, 2855),
                                ST_Transform(roa.wkb_geometry, 2855)) AS distance
FROM public.street_lights lig, public.roads roa
WHERE lig.ogc_fid = 1
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;

 ogc_fid |     distance     
---------+------------------
       2 | 61533.2214579388
(1 Zeile)
```

Question 2:

> how I should modify query to add new column to public.street_lights
>   where will be road_id with distance is minimum.

You can create a new column using an `ALTER TABLE` statement, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE public.street_lights ADD COLUMN road_id_min_dist INT;
```

And to populate this new column with the `road_id` you can use the same query within a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT lig.ogc_fid AS light_id, roa.ogc_fid AS road_id, 
    ST_Distance(ST_Transform(lig.wkb_geometry, 2855),
                ST_Transform(roa.wkb_geometry, 2855)) AS distance
  FROM public.street_lights lig, public.roads roa
  ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1)
UPDATE public.street_lights SET road_id_min_dist = j.road_id
FROM j WHERE j.light_id = ogc_fid;
```

And here is your data ..

```
SELECT ogc_fid,ST_AsText(wkb_geometry), road_id_min_dist 
FROM street_lights;

 ogc_fid | st_astext  | road_id_min_dist 
---------+------------+------------------
       1 | POINT(1 2) |                2
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: yes, something like that, but I found my own solution
but now my second question is still actual